# NestJs Body() is not populating with request information when coupled with serverless

Tags: serverless, nestjs

When running SLS Offline or SLS Deploy the body decorator in nest isn't being populated with the object being passed.

I have assembled a small repo to investigate the issue for anyone interested.

```
https://gitlab.com/claridgicus/nest-serverless-body-issue
```

SLS Offline output

```
[Nest] 91880   - 2019-04-24 20:58   [ExceptionHandler] Map#toJSON isn't generic +5ms
TypeError: Map#toJSON isn't generic
    at String.toJSON (c:\Users\Claridgicus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\core-js\modules\_collection-to-json.js:6:38)
    at Function.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Claridgicus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\core-js\modules\_ctx.js:18:15)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Function.stringify [as default] (c:\Users\Claridgicus\code\serverless-nestjs-master\node_modules\fast-safe-stringify\index.js:11:18)
    at ModuleTokenFactory.getDynamicMetadataToken (c:\Users\Claridgicus\code\serverless-nestjs-master\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\module-token-factory.js:20:69)
    at ModuleTokenFactory.create (c:\Users\Claridgicus\code\serverless-nestjs-master\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\module-token-factory.js:12:27)
    at ModuleCompiler.compile (c:\Users\Claridgicus\code\serverless-nestjs-master\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\compiler.js:19:47)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
 1: std::vector<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame,std::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame> >::vector<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame,std::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame> >
 2: v8::internal::wasm::SignatureMap::Find
 3: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor
 4: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor
 5: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor
 6: 0000006B886843C1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So

After much poking around - I double checked my headers on the incoming request

On the incoming POST request from the fed - Double check you are setting the headers - and save yourself the couple of hours unlike me :)

```
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
```